# java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Void

Tags: jpa, spring-mvc, spring-data

Estou tentando efetuar um UPDATE na tabela Usuario, porém ao fazer o submit ocorre erro. Estou com dificuldade em entender o que se trata o erro, poderiam me ajudar?
abaixo está meu código e o erro que está ocorrendo.

**Página:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
        xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
        layout:decorate="~{LayoutPadrao}">
<head>
    <title>Cadastro Usuario</title>
</head>
<section layout:fragment="conteudo">
    <div th:class="${classe}" th:if="${!#strings.isEmpty(mensagem)}">
        <span th:text="${mensagem}">Mensagem vem do Controller</span>
    </div>
    <form class="card" th:method="${action} == editar ? 'PUT' : 'POST'" th:action="${action} == 'editar' ? @{/usuario/editar/{codigo}(codigo=${usuario.getId_Usuario()})} : @{/usuario/salvarUsuario}" th:object="${usuario}">
        <h5 class="card-header">Cadastro de Usuário</h5>
        <div class="card-body">
            <input type="hidden" name="id_usuario" th:value="${usuario.getId_Usuario()}"/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="txtUsuario">Usuário</label>
                <input type="text" required class="form-control col-md-6" id="txtUsuario" name="usuario" th:field="*{usuario}" placeholder="Usuario"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="txtSenha">Senha</label>
                <input type="password" required class="form-control col-md-6" id="txtSenha" name="senha" th:field="*{senha}" placeholder="Senha"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="txtEmail">E-mail</label>
                <input type="email" required class="form-control col-md-6" id="txtEmail" name="email" th:field="*{email}" placeholder="nome@exemplo.com"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="dataCadastro" class="">Data de Cadastro</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" required class="form-control col-sm-2"   id="dataCadastro" name="dataCadastro"
                        data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-date-language="pt-BR"
                        data-date-autoclose="true" data-date-today-highlight="true" data-date-orientation="auto"
                        placeholder="Ex.: dd/mm/aaaa" data-mask="00/00/0000" maxlength="10" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ddlSituacao">Situação</label>
                <select class="form-control col-sm-2" id="ddlSituacao" name="status">
                    <option th:each="status : ${todosStatusUsuario}" th:value="${status}" th:text="${status.descricao}"></option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">Salvar</button>
                <button type="button" onClick="javascript:history.back()" class="btn btn-secondary col-sm-1">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/usuario")
public class UsuarioController {
        
    private static final String USUARIO_LISTA = "UsuarioLista";
    private static final String REDIRECT_USUARIO_LISTA = "redirect:/usuario";
    private static final String USUARIO_ACAO = "UsuarioAcao";
    private static final String REDIRECT_USUARIO_ACAO = "redirect:/usuario/novo";
    
    @Autowired UsuarioServices usuarioServices;
    
    @RequestMapping("/novo")
    public ModelAndView novo() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(USUARIO_ACAO);
        mv.addObject("todosStatusUsuario", StatusUsuario.values());
        mv.addObject(new Usuario());
        return mv;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/salvarUsuario", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String salvar(@ModelAttribute("form") @Validated Usuario usuario, Errors erros, RedirectAttributes attributes) {
        
        if(erros.hasErrors()) {
            Usuario form = new Usuario();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(form, usuario);
            return USUARIO_ACAO;
        }
        
        if(usuario.getId_Usuario() != null) {
            if(usuarioServices.usuarioExiste(usuario)) {
                attributes.addFlashAttribute("classe", "alert alert-warning");
                attributes.addFlashAttribute("mensagem", "Usuário já existe!");
                attributes.addFlashAttribute("usuario", usuario.getUsuario());
                attributes.addFlashAttribute("senha", usuario.getSenha());
                attributes.addFlashAttribute("email", usuario.getEmail());
                return REDIRECT_USUARIO_ACAO;
            }
        }
        
        try {
            usuarioServices.salvarUsuario(usuario);
            attributes.addFlashAttribute("classe", "alert alert-success");
            attributes.addFlashAttribute("mensagem", "Usuário salvo com sucesso!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            attributes.addFlashAttribute("classe", "alert alert-danger");
            attributes.addFlashAttribute("mensagem", ex.getMessage());
        }
        return REDIRECT_USUARIO_ACAO;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "{codigo}")
    public ModelAndView editar(@PathVariable Long codigo) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(USUARIO_ACAO);
        Usuario usuario = usuarioServices.buscaPorId(codigo);
        mv.addObject(usuario);
        mv.addObject("action", "editar");
        return mv;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "editar/{codigo}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ModelAndView editarUsuario(@ModelAttribute("form") @Validated Usuario usuario, @PathVariable Long codigo) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(USUARIO_LISTA);
        usuarioServices.editarPorUsuario(usuario, codigo);
        return mv;
    }
        
}
```

**UsuarioServices:**

```
package com.SystemsSolutions.WebControl.service;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.SystemsSolutions.WebControl.model.Perfil;
import com.SystemsSolutions.WebControl.model.Usuario;
import com.SystemsSolutions.WebControl.repository.UsuarioRepository;

@Service
public class UsuarioServices implements UserDetailsService{
    
    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository repository;
    
    //salva novo usuário
    public void salvarUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        try {
            Date data = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
            usuario.setSenha(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(usuario.getSenha()));
            usuario.setDataAlteracao(data); //GET DATA
            usuario.setHoraAlteracao(data); //GET HORA
            repository.save(usuario);
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex.getMessage());
        }
        
    }
    
    public Usuario buscaPorId(Long id) {
        Optional<Usuario> lista = repository.findById(id);
        if(!lista.isEmpty())
            return lista.get();
        return null;
    }
    
    @Transactional()
    public void editarPorUsuario(Usuario usuario, Long id) {
        Date data = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        usuario.setId_Usuario(id);
        usuario.setSenha(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(usuario.getSenha()));
        usuario.setDataAlteracao(data); //GET DATA
        usuario.setHoraAlteracao(data); //GET HORA
        repository.EditByUsuario(
                usuario.getUsuario()
                , usuario.getSenha()
                , usuario.getEmail()
                , usuario.getDataAlteracao()
                , usuario.getHoraAlteracao()
                , usuario.getDataCadastro()
                , usuario.getStatus()
                , id);
    }
    
    //busca usuário por usuário no banco de dados
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Usuario buscarPorUsuario(String usuario) {
        return repository.findByUsuario(usuario);
    }
    
    //busca usuário por email no banco de dados
    public Usuario buscarPorEmail(String email) {
        return repository.findByEmail(email);
    }
    
    //busca todos os usuários
    public List<Usuario> buscarTodos(){
        return repository.findAll();
    }
    
    public void deletar(Long id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }
    
    //autenticação de usuário (spring-security)
    @Override @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String user) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Usuario usuario = buscarPorUsuario(user);
        System.out.println("Usuário encontrado: " + usuario.getUsuario()
                        +  "\nSenha: " + usuario.getSenha()
                        +  "\nStatus: " + usuario.getStatus());
        
        if(usuario.getStatus().toString().equals("BLOQUEADO") || usuario.getStatus().toString().equals("PENDENTE")) {
            usuario = null;
        }
        
        return new User(
                usuario.getUsuario(),
                usuario.getSenha(),
                AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(getAuthorities(usuario.getPerfis()))
        );
    }
    //converte lista de perfis para array string
    private String[] getAuthorities(List<Perfil> perfis) {
        String[] authorities = new String[perfis.size()];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < perfis.size(); i++) {
            authorities[i] = perfis.get(i).getDesc();
        }
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

**UsuarioRepository**

```
package com.SystemsSolutions.WebControl.repository;

import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import com.SystemsSolutions.WebControl.model.StatusUsuario;
import com.SystemsSolutions.WebControl.model.Usuario;

public interface UsuarioRepository extends JpaRepository<Usuario, Long> {
    //From deve ser identico ao nome da classe, tal classe deve estar mapeada como Entity
    //nome da coluna deve ser identico ao nome do atributo da classe
    @Query("SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.usuario = :usuarioParam")
    Usuario findByUsuario(@Param("usuarioParam") String usuario);
    
    @Query("SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.email = :emailParam")
    Usuario findByEmail(@Param("emailParam") String email);
    
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Usuario u "
            + "SET u.usuario        = :usuarioParam"
            + ", u.senha            = :senhaParam"
            + ", u.email            = :emailParam"
            + ", u.dataAlteracao    = :dataAltParam"
            + ", u.horaAlteracao    = :horaAltParam"
            + ", u.dataCadastro     = :dataCadParam"
            + ", u.status           = :statusParam "
            + "WHERE u.id_usuario = :idParam")
    Void EditByUsuario(@Param("usuarioParam") String usuario
                        , @Param("senhaParam") String senha
                        , @Param("emailParam") String email
                        , @Param("dataAltParam") Date dataAlteracao
                        , @Param("horaAltParam") Date horaAlteracao
                        , @Param("dataCadParam") Date dataCadastro
                        , @Param("statusParam") StatusUsuario status
                    , @Param("idParam")Long id);
    
}
```

**ERRO**

```
2021-02-17 17:18:50.982 DEBUG 11504 --- [nio-8081-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : PUT "/usuario/editar/8", parameters={masked}
2021-02-17 17:18:50.982 DEBUG 11504 --- [nio-8081-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.SystemsSolutions.WebControl.controller.UsuarioController#editarUsuario(Usuario, Long)
2021-02-17 17:18:51.085 DEBUG 11504 --- [nio-8081-exec-8] org.hibernate.SQL                        : update usuario set usuario=?, senha=?, email=?, data_alteracao=?, hora_alteracao=?, data_cadastro=?, status=? where id_usuario=?
Hibernate: update usuario set usuario=?, senha=?, email=?, data_alteracao=?, hora_alteracao=?, data_cadastro=?, status=? where id_usuario=?
2021-02-17 17:18:51.085 TRACE 11504 --- [nio-8081-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [EMERSON]
2021-02-17 17:18:51.086 TRACE 11504 --- [nio-8081-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [$2a$10$tUBTCwTcRTEJgjcHln8NGeVdD.b6kzayoqOF44UELVPRk6wd.v6nS]
2021-02-17 17:18:51.086 TRACE 11504 --- [nio-8081-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [emersoro@gmail.com]
2021-02-17 17:18:51.086 TRACE 11504 --- [nio-8081-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [DATE] - [Wed Feb 17 17:18:50 BRT 2021]
2021-02-17 17:18:51.086 TRACE 11504 --- [nio-8081-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [TIME] - [Wed Feb 17 17:18:50 BRT 2021]
2021-02-17 17:18:51.086 TRACE 11504 --- [nio-8081-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [6] as [DATE] - [Wed Feb 17 00:00:00 BRT 2021]
2021-02-17 17:18:51.086 TRACE 11504 --- [nio-8081-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [7] as [VARCHAR] - [ATIVO]
2021-02-17 17:18:51.086 TRACE 11504 --- [nio-8081-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [8] as [BIGINT] - [8]
2021-02-17 17:18:51.092 DEBUG 11504 --- [nio-8081-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Void (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.Void are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
2021-02-17 17:18:51.096 ERROR 11504 --- [nio-8081-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Void (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.Void are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')] with root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Void (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.Void are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy456.EditByUsuario(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy453.EditByUsuario(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.SystemsSolutions.WebControl.service.UsuarioServices.editarPorUsuario(UsuarioServices.java:59) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.SystemsSolutions.WebControl.service.UsuarioServices$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3ab2fb79.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.SystemsSolutions.WebControl.service.UsuarioServices$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$772b0101.editarPorUsuario(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.SystemsSolutions.WebControl.controller.UsuarioController.editarUsuario(UsuarioController.java:91) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seguinte método:

```
Void EditByUsuario(@Param("usuarioParam") String usuario
                    , @Param("senhaParam") String senha
                    , @Param("emailParam") String email
                    , @Param("dataAltParam") Date dataAlteracao
                    , @Param("horaAltParam") Date horaAlteracao
                    , @Param("dataCadParam") Date dataCadastro
                    , @Param("statusParam") StatusUsuario status
                    , @Param("idParam") Long id);
```

O tipo `Void` não é suportado. Você provavelmente estava procurando pelo tipo `void`.

De acordo com a [documentação do Spring Data](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/2.1.5/reference/html/#jdbc.query-methods.at-query.modifying), o retorno da função também pode ser:

- `boolean`: `true` se alguma linha foi alterada, `false` caso contrário; ou
- `int`: retorna o número de linhas alteradas.

Conforme [o apêndice D do Spring Data JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-return-types) *wrappers* (e.g., `Integer`e `Boolean`) também são suportados.

O Spring Data está se perdendo com a assinatura de método com um tipo de retorno não suportado. A implementação gerada pela biblioteca está tentando converter um tipo `Integer` para o tipo `Void`.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Void (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.Void are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap').

Dito isso, uma vez que você está usando [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate) com o [spring-data](/questions/tagged/spring-data), o método `editByUsuario` e seu *update statement* explícito em JPQL me parecem desnecessários. Você pode fazer a mesma coisa com métodos padrão do [`JpaRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html).

```
@Transactional
public void editarPorUsuario(Usuario usuario, Long id) {
    // assumindo que usuario é detached
    // obtém uma referência para o usuário administrado pelo contexto de persistência
    Usuario managedUser = repository.getOne(id); 
    // Copia dados a serem atualizados
    Date data = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    managedUser.setUsuario(usuario.getUsuario());
    managedUser.setSenha(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(usuario.getSenha()));
    managedUser.setEmail(usuario.getEmail());
    // ... outros campos a serem atualizados
    managedUser.setDataAlteracao(data);
    managedUser.setHoraAlteracao(data); 

    /* Opcionalmente você pode chamar operações de save ou saveAndFlush
     * Mas veja que como você já tem uma transação aberta isso costuma ser
     * um anti-pattern: https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persist-and-merge/
     */
}
```

Na verdade, os outros dois métodos de `UsuarioRepository` também podem ser simplificados uma vez que o Spring Data consegue [derivar a consulta do nome do método](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details). Parece que você já está usando a nomenclatura correta para [criar consultas](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation), o em ambos os casos o uso de [`@Query`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) e [`@Param`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters) são desnecessários. Porém isso foge ao escopo da pergunta.

Comment: Deu certo, mudei o retorno para Integer e funcionou. valeu parceiro.